# Feedback on solving this javascript question.. how to solve splitting array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to javascript and am having trouble solving this problem. This is the code I have entered and would like some feedback on where I'm going wrong/how I can solve this please and how to handle the callback.

Question: It will take two parameters, the first is an array of Integer values, and the second will be a callback which will return a boolean. If the callback returns true for an element, it should be placed into the left array, otherwise it should be placed into the right array.

```
const partition = function(arr, callback) {
  let leftArr = [];
  let rightArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
      leftArr.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      (rightArr.push(arr[i]));
    }
    }
    return [leftArr, rightArr];
  };
```

Comment: You aren't ever calling the callback.

Comment: you could write the `callback` check in the if condition and then proceed `arr[i] % 2 === 0 || callback(<your logic>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const partition = function(arr, callback) {
  //returns 2 arrays
  //if n % 2 === 0 => left
  //else => right, callback which returns a boolean
  let leftArr = [];
  let rightArr = [];
  
  arr.map(i => {
    if(callback(i)) {
      leftArr.push(i)
    } else {
      rightArr.push(i)
    }
  })
  return [leftArr, rightArr];
};
  
console.log(partition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], (i) => i % 2 === 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

This callback is a function:
which will return true if condition satisfied other wise it will return false
so you will use it like this:

```
const partition = function(arr, callback) {
  //returns 2 arrays
  //if n % 2 === 0 => left
  //else => right, callback which returns a boolean
  let leftArr = [];
  let rightArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (callback(arr[i])) {
      leftArr.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      rightArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    }
    return [leftArr, rightArr];
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript array filter.

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

const arr2 = arr.filter(num => num % 2 === 0);
const arr3 = arr.filter(num => num % 2 !== 0);

console.log(arr2); // [2,4,6,8]
console.log(arr3); // [1,3,5,7,9]
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're not using the callback to determine is a number is odd or even. Define the function `isEven` and pass it in to the function as the callback. You can then call it on each loop iteration to check the number.

```js
// Passing in the callback
// I've renamed it `isEven` to make the code
// easier to understand
const partition = function(arr, isEven) {

  let leftArr = [];
  let rightArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    
    const el = arr[i];

    // In your condition call the callback
    // function with the current element
    if (isEven(el)) {
      leftArr.push(el);
    } else {
      rightArr.push(el);
    }

  }

  return [leftArr, rightArr];

};

const arr = [0, 3, 1, 6, 7, 22, 100];

// Accepts a number and returns true
// depending if the number is even
const isEven = (n) => n % 2 === 0;

console.log(partition(arr, isEven));
```